# Passing URL as parameter in JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
var url = f.href.value;
ed.dom.setAttribs(e, {
    href : 'javascript:void(0)',
    onclick: 'doSomething(' + url + ')'
});
```

And the doSomething method:

```
function doSomething(url) {
    windowMy = dhxWins.createWindow("externalLink", 10, 10, 630, 630);
    windowMy.setText("Title");
    windowMy.attachURL(url);
}
```

When doSomething is called, I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :, when url="http://somewebsite/site".

What should I do? How can I pass url as parameter in JS function?

Comment: The string you create is something like `something(http://...)` which is not a valid JavaScript function call. The argument has to be put in quotes to be interpreted as string literal.

Comment: That is not jQuery, I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 7):

I think you just need some extra quotes around your url:

```
var url = f.href.value;
ed.dom.setAttribs(e, {
    href : 'javascript:void(0)',
    onclick: 'doSomething("' + url + '")'
});
```

Otherwise, the function ends up like this:

```
doSomething(http://www.google.com);
```

Instead of:

```
doSomething("http://www.google.com");
```